# Load Balancing Java RMI Requests

Tags: java, rmi, load-balancing

I am trying to find a solution for load balancing b/w multiple RMI servers running same service API.

Are there any solutions you have used or would recommend?

Comment: You can use DNS round robin. It should be simple to implement if requests are stateless/ non-conversational.

Comment: @BimaleshJha thx for the advise but this will cause issues if one of the server becomes unavailable and DNS will have to no way to do the health check and stop sending out the IP of bad server to the clients.

Comment: You should build sufficient **application logic** to timeout and retry with a new location or have some kind of `heartbeat` mechansim. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: What Server do you use? I could imagine some Containers have support for this.

Comment: Any new findings here? I would be interested in a simple load-balancing to be used directly in the client too.

Answer (score 0):

Change to RMI/IIOP and use a load-balancing ORB of your choice.